# Canvas line clear and re-draw from array

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

I'm having a problem where I try to draw lines on a canvas from an array.
I'm trying to clear the canvas once before the first line is drawn.
If I clear the canvas I only get the last line drawn instead of all of them.

```
function drawAll() {
    for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
        if (i == 0) {
            ctx2.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height); // clears canvas 
        }
        ctx2.beginPath(); // needed to clear canvas if drawing lines
        ctx2.moveTo(lines[i].start.x, lines[i].start.y);
        ctx2.lineTo(lines[i].end.x, lines[i].end.y);
        ctx2.stroke();
    }
}
```

Am i doing something wrong?

https://jsfiddle.net/1tgcd9xu/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is not in the drawing part, but in the line update (that you may want to include in your question btw).

#### You are using one and only `lineObj` object.

The one you update is always the same, what you push in your Array is always the same Object.

So when you come to `drawAll`, your code will correctly iterate over all the references to this same `lineObj`, and will correctly draw its current state, as many times as you pushed new references to it in the Array.

To fix it, you need to create a new Object at least every time you push it to your Array.
But you may also be interested in prototyping these lines so that you can make use of helper methods which will probably come handy once your project will grow.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var canvas2 = document.getElementById("myCanvas2");

var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var ctx2 = canvas2.getContext("2d");
var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
var xPos;
var yPos;
var pressed = 0;
var lines = [];
var line = [];

function drawCanvas() {
  ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(255, 0, 0)";
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 150, 75);
  ctx2.fillStyle = "rgb(255, 0, 0)";
  ctx2.fillRect(0, 0, 150, 75);
}


function drawLine() {
  if (pressed != 0) { // stops from drawing a line after two mouse presses
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height); // clears canvas   
    ctx.beginPath(); // needed to clear canvas if drawing lines
    ctx.moveTo(xPos, yPos); //  line start
    endXPos = event.clientX - rect.left;
    endYPos = event.clientY - rect.top;
    ctx.lineTo(endXPos, endYPos);
    ctx.stroke();
    writeMessage();
  }
}

function drawAll() {
  // better to move it out of the loop
  if (lines.length) {
    ctx2.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height); // clears canvas 
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
    ctx2.beginPath(); // needed to clear canvas if drawing lines
    ctx2.moveTo(lines[i].start.x, lines[i].start.y);
    ctx2.lineTo(lines[i].end.x, lines[i].end.y);
    ctx2.stroke();
  }
}

function writeMessage() {
  document.getElementById("coordinates").innerHTML =
  "Mouse Position: " +
    (event.clientX - rect.left) + ", " +
    (event.clientY - rect.top);
}

function mouseDownFunction(event) {
  pressed++;
  xPos = event.clientX - rect.left; // x and y cordinates of mouse on canvas
  yPos = event.clientY - rect.top;
  if (pressed == 1) { // reset our global lineObj
    lineObj.reset(xPos, yPos);
    ctx.moveTo(xPos, yPos);
  } else if (pressed == 2) { // update our global lineObj
    lineObj.update(xPos, yPos);
    ctx.lineTo(xPos, yPos)
    // push a clone of the current status
    lines.push(lineObj.clone());
    pressed = 0;
    drawAll();
  }
}
// LineObject Constructor
/**
 * @method reset(xPos, yPos) ::resets both `start` and `end` positions
 * @method update(xPos, yPos) ::Updates `end`
 * @method clone() ::Returns a new LineObject with this current positions
 *
 * Feel free to add more, like `draw`, `setColor`...
 *
*/
function LineObject(xPos, yPos) {
  this.start = {
    x: xPos,
    y: yPos
  };
  this.end = {
    x: xPos,
    y: yPos
  }
}
LineObject.prototype = {
  reset: function(xPos, yPos) {
    this.start.x = this.end.x = xPos;
    this.start.y = this.end.y = yPos;
  },
  update: function(xPos, yPos) {
    this.end.x = xPos;
    this.end.y = yPos;
  },
  clone: function() {
    var clone = new LineObject(this.start.x, this.start.y);
    clone.update(this.end.x, this.end.y);
    return clone;
  }
};
var lineObj = new LineObject();

canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", drawLine)
//   on mouse move inside canvas execute writeMessage

canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", mouseDownFunction)
//   on left click inside canvas execute setLineStart
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>
<h1 id="coordinates"></h1>
<h1 id="hehe"></h1>
<canvas id="myCanvas2">
  Your browser does not support the canvas element.
</canvas>
```